# Modal window will not open twice in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, simplemodal

In Chrome and all other browsers this works fine, but in IE once the modal window opens once and I close it, I cannot open the window again. It just flashes quickly on the screen and then disappears.

Why? Here is my code:

```
fullmsg = "";
if ($('input[id*=field1]:checked').val() == "*")
{
  msg = "field1";
  if (fullmsg == "") { fullmsg = msg; }
  else {  fullmsg = fullmsg + "\n" + msg; }
 }


 if (fullmsg != "") {

     fullmsg =  " MANDATORY fields above have not been filled in"
     $("#errmsg").val(fullmsg);
     $("#errorpopup").modal(
     {
            appendTo: 'form',
            opacity: 40,
            overlayCss:
            {  backgroundColor: "#fff"  }
           ,
           onClose: function (dialog) {
                document.getElementById('<%=hpage.ClientID%>').value = nextpage;
                document.forms["mainform"].submit();
                dialog.overlay.fadeOut('fast');
                dialog.container.fadeOut('fast');
                dialog.data.fadeOut('fast');
                $.modal.close();
            }
     }
     );
     event.preventDefault();
  }
  else
  {
    dialog.overlay.fadeOut('fast');
    dialog.container.fadeOut('fast');
    dialog.data.fadeOut('fast');
    $.modal.close();
  }
```